# RDFox daemon port

Tags: sparql, daemon, datalog, rdfox

I am using RDFox 3.0.1, and I cannot figure out how to specify the port the daemon should start on.

I have tried:

```
./RDFox daemon . "set endpoint.port 8080" "endpoint start"
```

This seems to work in v2.1.1, but not in 3.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running in `daemon` mode, then after the daemon keyword you can specify the endpoint parameters. These are exactly the same as in the shell, but without the `endpoint. prefix.`

So, if in the shell you did `set endpoint.blah value`, you specify this option as `RDFox daemon blah value`.

For example `./RDFox daemon port 8080`